# How to open the Facebook App with an Android app?

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-studio

I am trying to open the Facebook App or Facebook's page with an android app but I can't do it. It doesn't do anything.

Here is the code:

```
public Intent getOpenFacebookIntent(Context context){

    try{
        context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.FacebookSdk", 0);
        return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://page/ID"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/my_page"));
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick (View v){
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.guardar:
          startActivity(new Intent(this, getOpenFacebookIntent(this)));
        break;
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

**Package name should be this.**

```
details?id=com.facebook.katana
```

**Chage this.**

```
context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.FacebookSdk", 0);
```

**To this.**

```
context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
```

**EDIT1:**

```
Intent facebookIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String facebookUrl = getOpenFacebookIntent(this);
facebookIntent.setData(Uri.parse(facebookUrl));
startActivity(facebookIntent);
```

Comment: where should I change the package name??

Comment: Change in the line where you getting package info see my answer.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Also, there seems to be a problem with the startActivity, do you know why? @jaydroider

Comment: What you are doing with start activity is wrong. you need to pass like this `startActivity(new Intent(FirstActivity.this, DestinationActivity.this));`

Comment: @AldoT Can you tell me exact problem with startActivity what is happening wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Call: `launchFacebook();` in your onClick() method

```
public void launchFacebook() {
    String urlFb = "fb://page/"+ID;
    // replace ID with your id 
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(urlFb));

    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    if (list.size() == 0) {
        final String urlBrowser = "https://www.facebook.com/"+my_page; 
        // relpace my_page with facebook profile page ending
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(urlBrowser));
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}
```